# handleInviteFromGameCenter handling for turn based game (iOS6)

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center, invitation

The standard handleInviteFromGameCenter event handling (when inviting someone from GC-app for a turn based match) behaves strange under iOS6: when I provide the playerToInvite array to the GKMatchRequest and open the GC turn based match controller, it shows "Waiting..." under that invited player (which it IMHO shouldn't for a turn based game). It never stops. When I add another player manually and press "play", it just starts with me and that newly added player, ignoring the one being passed from playerToInvite array.
Any insights on this behaviour?

Thx, habitoti

Comment: How do you get GameCenter to call handleInviteFromGameCenter in the first place?  When I invite a player it is just putting them directly into the match.

Comment: Go to the GC app and select a friend owning your app. Select the app in the friend view and tap "Play". It will then start your app and once GC user is authenticated, it will call that event with the playersToInvite array containg the invited player.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue on iPhone vs iPad?

Comment: No, same behaviour on iOS6 iPhone. It _does_ work on iPhone iOS5, but "funny enough" it crashes on iPad iOS5 with an NSIndexPath assertion in the GC UI.
So as it stands now, from all current setups this only works in iPhone with iOS 5...